# Extjs align buttons center in container

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have following container with several buttons:

```
{
                    xtype : 'container',
                    width : 320,
                    layout : 'hbox',
                    cls : 'readable-form no-border',
                    labelSeparator : '',
                    ref : '../sendBackForm',
                    layoutConfig: {
                        padding:'5',
                        pack:'center',
                        align:'middle'
                    },
                    style : {
                        margin : 'auto'
                    },
                    items : [ {
                        xtype : 'button',
                        itemId : 'yes',
                        iconCls : 'save-button-icon',
                        text : 'Yes',
                        ref : '../../yes'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'spacer',
                        width : 10
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'button',
                        itemId : 'checker',
                        iconCls : 'save-button-icon',
                        text : 'Back to checker',
                        ref : '../../checker'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'spacer',
                        width : 10
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'button',
                        itemId : 'prebooker',
                        iconCls : 'save-button-icon',
                        text : 'Back to prebooker',
                        ref : '../../prebooker'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'spacer',
                        width : 10
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'button',
                        itemId : 'cancel',
                        text : 'Cancel',
                        ref : '../../cancel'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'spacer',
                        width : 90
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'button',
                        itemId : 'ok',
                        hidden : true,
                        text : 'Ok',
                        ref : '../../ok'
                    } ]

                }
```

the problem is when i hide all buttons and want to show only ok button, it appears near left window corner, how i can place it in the middle of the window?

Comment: what is the version of Extjs you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [layoutConfig won't work anymore](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?124877-CLOSED-hbox-layout-layoutConfig-parameters-pack-and-align-not-working) Set 'pack' and 'align' in layout config itself, [fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18l) (Click on 'Yes' button to hide all except 'Ok')

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried you add this following code on your container ? : `autoEl: {tag: 'center'}`

Answer (score 1):

you can try placing spacers before and after "OK" button,

```
...
items: [
...
{xtype: 'tbspacer', flex: 1},
{
    xtype : 'button',
    itemId : 'btnok',
    hidden : true,
    text : 'Ok',
    ref : '../../ok'
},
{xtype: 'tbspacer', flex: 1}
...
```

and "OK" and "Cancel" button handlers

```
....
bindHandlers: function(){
    var me = this;
    me.getComponent('btnok').on('click', function(){
        me.toggleButtons(true);
    });

    me.getComponent('btncancel').on('click', function(){
        me.toggleButtons(false);
    });      
},
toggleButtons: function(visible){
    this.getComp('btnyes').setVisible(visible);
    this.getComp('checker').setVisible(visible);
    this.getComp('prebooker').setVisible(visible);
    this.getComp('btncancel').setVisible(visible);
    this.getComp('btnok').setVisible(!visible);
}
...
```

Or manually add spacers before and after "OK" button

Comment: This saves my day.